# How to swap svg icons in Visual

Tags: svg

I would like to swap my icon to the new one, and when i am trying to do this, the icon has width 0:

Here is the old icon when everything is work:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="21" viewBox="1.5 2 21 21">
<defs>
  <style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#200e32;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:1.5px;}</style>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(2.778 2.778)">
  <circle class="a" cx="8.989" cy="8.989" r="8.989"/>
  <path class="a" d="M0,0,3.524,3.515" transform="translate(15.24 15.707)"/>
</g></svg>
```

And here is my new svg icon:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Warstwa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="21" height="21" viewBox="0 0 92.2 96.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 92.2 96.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#211632;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#DD0B17;}
</style>
<g id="Search_00000004544498495213549680000015772338155846502573_" 
   transform="translate(0.75 0.75)">
    <circle class='a' id="Ellipse_739_00000077287522015738190650000001649653396756373183_" 
                class="st0" cx="44.7" cy="47.2" r="9"/>
    <path class='a' id="Line_181_00000065792884007969668160000004498486002685306540_" 
              class="st0" d="M50.9,53.9l3.5,3.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

And the problem is - I can't see new icon on page - It is cuz i can click on it, but the width = 0. I set the width = 21 so why i can't see it on page?

Answer (score 0):

You specified the class attribute on `<circle>` and `<path>` twice. So, the styles in the `.st0` where not applied. I think it works here, but still the icon i quite small:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="21" viewBox="0 0 92.2 96.2">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#211632;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#DD0B17;}
  </style>
  <g id="Search_00000004544498495213549680000015772338155846502573_" 
    transform="translate(0.75 0.75)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_739_00000077287522015738190650000001649653396756373183_" 
                class="st0" cx="44.7" cy="47.2" r="9"/>
    <path id="Line_181_00000065792884007969668160000004498486002685306540_" 
              class="st0" d="M50.9,53.9l3.5,3.5"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```